# Dynamic text fields for a drop box

Tags: javascript, jquery

We are stuck up in a module which had an option of enclosures. The enclosures is a drop down box and if no. of enclosures is selected 1, 1 text field must be generated, if 2 enclosures are selected, 2 text fields must be generated dynamically and maximum requirement is 4. please help us!

Comment: Give some code to test, show us what you have tried?

Comment: How can we possibly help you? You haven't shown us anything to work with: show us your code, help *us* to help **you**.

Comment: <select name="enclosure" id="enclosure" >
     <option value="">Enclosure</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3">3</option>
     <option value="4">4</option></select>

Comment: so if my selection is 1..i must get a text-field, 2 enclosures--> 2 text-fields respectively !

Comment: Please show us your code edit your question and pasted it there, not in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<select name="enclosure" id="enclosure" >
    <option value="">Enclosure</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div id="textBox-container"></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change','#enclosure',function(){
        var no=$(this).val();
        if(no)
        {
            $('#textBox-container').html('');
            for(i=0;i<no;i++)
            {
                $('#textBox-container').append('<input type="text" id="txtBox_'+(i+1)+'" value="'+(i+1)+'"/>');
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating at max four text box and use show/hide for user as per the selected option in drop down. For eg:

```
    if(val == 1){
        $("input[id$='textbox2']").hide();
        $("input[id$='textbox3']").hide();
        $("input[id$='textbox4']").hide();
    } else if(val == 2){
        $("input[id$='textbox3']").hide();
        $("input[id$='textbox4']").hide();
    } else if(val == 3){
        $("input[id$='textbox4']").hide();
    }
```

Hope this might help you.

Comment: Approach will need to be change in case if you are having more number of textbox. This will work in case if you are having low number of dynamic element t display.